# Get Azure Blob storage region using .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to get the (primary) Azure region in which a Blob Storage account is deployed in using the WindowsAzure.Storage .NET SDK (using the latest version 9.1.1)?

If not by using the storage SDK, which other way would there be from .NET? Thanks!

Comment: Here's some documentation on using the REST API to get that info, but I don't see a way to do it with the SDK. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/getproperties

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the (primary) Azure region in which a Blob
>   Storage account is deployed in using the WindowsAzure.Storage .NET SDK
>   (using the latest version 9.1.1)?

Unfortunately no. `WindowsAzure.Storage` .NET SDK is for managing data in your Azure Storage accounts.

> If not by using the storage SDK, which other way would there be from
>   .NET? Thanks!

You will need to use [`Azure Management Library for .Net`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) for this purpose.